# How to add two different Image for point annotation in Mapbox?

Tags: ios, swift, image, annotations, mapbox

I am using mapbox for my project. Here I have added the two annotation:

```
 func showFromAnnotation(){
        
        let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: fromLat, longitude: fromLon)
        annotation.title = fromHouseName
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        
        let annotation1 = MGLPointAnnotation()
        annotation1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: toLat, longitude: toLon)
        annotation1.title = toHouseName
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation1)
    }
```

In this Point annotation, I am trying to add an two different images in it and can't seem to work it out. i've tried doing it this way but this process doesn't seem to work.

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {

            var annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: "annotation")

               if annotationImage == nil {
                   var image = UIImage()

                   if  annotation.coordinate.latitude == fromLat{
                       image = UIImage(named: "location")!

                   }else  if  annotation.coordinate.latitude == toLat{
                       image = UIImage(named: "map7")!
                   }


                   image = image.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: image.size.height/2, right: 0))
                   annotationImage = MGLAnnotationImage(image: image, reuseIdentifier: "annotation")

               }
            return annotationImage

           }
```

if anyone could tell me how to do, It would be a great help.

Comment: Please explain 'doesn't seem to work' What happens? What version of Mapbox?

Comment: it is i guess Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 6.3.0

Comment: it only shows one image @Magnas